# Element not visible- selenium error

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on save button on a popup on the same window, the popup also has a text box, to which I am able to successfully send the text, but when I attempt to click the button, error comes as element not visible

Comment: what version of selenium are u using ?

Answer (score 4):

Element not visible exception can be resolved by using **Explicit wait**. Explicit wait in selenium will wait until the element is visible. Once it's visible you can perform the necessary operation.

**Syntax for Explicit wait**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
WebElement e = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your locator value")));
```

In the above code selenium will wait for 30 seconds until the element is visible and once it is visible, selenium will perform the required action on it.

Answer (score 1):

Give proper Wait command and try either of these below Xpath. This will work.

```
 //button[@id='search]

 //button[contains(text(),'Save')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from wait strategy, need to check if property wise visible is true on condition, otherwise different locator strategy if current one is not supporting as mentioned by others in this thread.